# How to parse a csv with python, when one column has multiple lines

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that is "name, place, thing". the thing column often has "word\nanotherword\nanotherword\n" I'm trying to figure out how to parse this out into individual lines instead of multiline entries in a single column. i.e.

`name, place, word`

`name, place, anotherword`

`name, place , anotherword`

I'm certain this is simple, but im having a hard time grasping what i need to do.

Comment: have you written any code for this yourself?

Comment: Check out the csv module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into the code, essentially what you want to do is check to see if there are any newline characters in your 'thing'. If there are, you need to split them on the newline characters. This will give you a list of tokens (the lines in the 'thing') and since this is essentially an inner loop, you can use the original `name` and `place` along with your new `thing_token`. A generator function lends itself well to this.

This is brings me to kroolik's answer. However, there's a slight error in kroolik's answer:

If you want to go with the `column_wrapper` generator, you will need to account for the fact that the csv reader escapes backslash in the newlines, so they look like `\\n` instead of `\n`. Also, you need to check for blank 'things'.

```
def column_wrapper(reader):
    for name, place, thing in reader:
        for split_thing in thing.strip().split('\\n'):
            if split_thing:
                yield name, place, split_thing
```

Then you can obtain the data like this:

```
with open('filewithdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = [[data, name, thing] for data, name, thing in column_wrapper(reader)]
```

OR (without `column_wrapper`):

```
data = []
with open('filewithdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        name, place, thing = tuple(row)
        if '\\n' in thing:
            for item in thing.split('\\n'):
                if item != '\n':
                    data.append([name, place, item)]
```

I recommend using `column_wrapper` as generators are more generic and pythonic.

Be sure to add `import csv` to the top of your file (although I'm sure you knew that already). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your csv reader with this `column_wrapper`:

```
def column_wrapper(reader):
    for name, place, thing in reader:
        for split_thing in thing.strip().split('\n'):
            yield name, place, split_thing
```

And you will be golden.

Answer (score 0):

You could always the file read line by line

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7.2
file = open("demo.csv", "r+");
for line in file:
   line =  line.replace(",", " ")
   words = line.split()
   print(words[0])
   print(words[1])
   print(words[2])   
file.close()
```

Assuming the file content is

```
name1,place1,word1
name2,place2,anotherword2
name3,place3,anotherword3
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone runs into this with the same issue I had. If you have multiline strings in on of your cells, use the quotechar field as specified in this answer:

[how to read a csv file that has multiple lines within the same cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511216/how-to-read-a-csv-file-that-has-multiple-lines-within-the-same-cell)