# Read in csv file with one column of strings in the middle

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy

I have a csv input file of standard format with a messy header that I am stripping off, and then an array of 35 columns and 8760 rows.  All of this data is numeric, except the 6th column, which is text. I have tried allowing `genfromtxt()` to figure this out on its own, but in the end that column is turned to `nan`s, I believe because there are no quotes.

Currently, I'm reading this array as follows:

```
WeaData = np.genfromtxt(FileIn, delimiter=",", skip_header=8)
```

I have tried specifying the column types manually with

```
WeaData = np.genfromtxt(FileIn, delimiter=",", skip_header=8, dtype=(float,float,float,float,float,str,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float))
```

and

```
WeaData = np.genfromtxt(FileIn, delimiter=",", skip_header=8, dtype=[float for n in range(5)]+['S10']+[float for n in range(29)])
```

but with no luck. I believe my syntax is wrong in the first option, and the second returns an array of voids. Is there a simple way to do this, preferably without specifying 35 column types?

Here are three lines of my csv file for reference, after the header I don't care about.

```
1966,1,1,1,60,A7A7A7A7*0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0A7A7A7A7A7A7F8F8A7E7,3.9,1.7,86,102400,0,0,264,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,230,2.1,0,0,24.1,77777,0,999999999,8,0.1000,0,88,0.000,0.0,0.0
1966,1,1,2,60,A7A7A7A7*0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0A7A7A7A7A7A7F8F8A7E7,4.4,0.0,73,102500,0,0,265,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,270,3.6,0,0,24.1,77777,0,999999999,8,0.1000,0,88,0.000,0.0,0.0
1966,1,1,3,60,A7A7A7A7*0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0A7A7A7A7A7A7F8F8A7E7,2.8,-0.6,79,102500,0,0,258,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,310,2.1,0,0,24.1,77777,0,999999999,8,0.1000,0,88,0.000,0.0,0.0
```

I'm using Python V2.7.

Comment: Hi, there are many ways to read a csv you should take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982437/how-to-parse-a-csv-with-python-when-one-column-has-multiple-lines)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to read it directly into a numpy array? You should probably look into `pandas`

Comment: Using a data file with just the three lines that you show, your second example works for me.  I changed 'S10' to 'S32' to make sure the text field wasn't truncated, and I didn't use the `skip_header` argument, since I didn't add a header.  When you specify a dtype like this, the function returns a structured array (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Is that what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.loadtxt` with the parameter `usecols` for selecting only the columns containing float numbers.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> cols = range(0,5) + range(6,35)
>>> data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",", usecols=cols, dtype=np.float)
>>> data
[[  1.96600000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
    6.00000000e+01   3.90000000e+00   1.70000000e+00   8.60000000e+01
    1.02400000e+05   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.64000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.30000000e+02
    2.10000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.41000000e+01
    7.77770000e+04   0.00000000e+00   9.99999999e+08   8.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e-01   0.00000000e+00   8.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.96600000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
    6.00000000e+01   4.40000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.30000000e+01
    1.02500000e+05   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.65000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.70000000e+02
    3.60000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.41000000e+01
    7.77770000e+04   0.00000000e+00   9.99999999e+08   8.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e-01   0.00000000e+00   8.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.96600000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00
    6.00000000e+01   2.80000000e+00  -6.00000000e-01   7.90000000e+01
    1.02500000e+05   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.58000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.10000000e+02
    2.10000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.41000000e+01
    7.77770000e+04   0.00000000e+00   9.99999999e+08   8.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e-01   0.00000000e+00   8.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

If you want to include the 6th column, then you will have to load the matrix as object, you can't mix floats with strings.

```
>>> data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=np.object)
```

So if you need this column, load it separately.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Somewhat new but continuing question -  then I need to be able to write everything back to a text file (In the same format from which I read it), but I have some columns as numeric types and that one as strings.  np.savetxt complains because not all the elements are floats.  What would be the best practice to save a numpy array of floats and strings to a text file?  Is there a clean direct way or might it require converting the whole thing to a string first?