# How to parse a file in python given the specific structure of the file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem when trying to parse a file, in which, for each row, I have a structure like the following, with all the strings that are in quotes:

`"is_post"  "author_name"  "timestamp"  "tags"  "text"`

All the data in the file are quoted too; this means that I may have something as:

`"True", "auth1", "1970:01:01T23:59:59", "soccer football match", "Just a great match!"`

The problem arises when the `"text"` field has `\n` inside, so, e.g.:

```
"True", "auth1", "1970:01:01T23:59:59", "soccer football match", "Just a great match!
Barcelona 2
Real Madrid 3

Real Madrid wins the match!"
```

In this case, in which way I can continue to read the file also in the next line up to arriving at the next quote?

What I've tried so far is as follows:

```
import shlex
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class Comment(NamedTuple):
    is_post: str
    author: str
    timestamp: str
    tags: str
    text: str

comments: List[Comment]


def open_comment_file(self):
    with open(self.operations + "comments.csv", "r") as f:
        for line in f:        
            arr = shlex.split(line)
            comments.append(Comment(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]))
```

But obviously, I don't take into consideration the case in which the `line` does not end with a quote, because I'm reading the file row by row.

How can I handle this situation?

EDIT: The result I want to get is, for the example above, a single row, as follows:

```
"True", "auth1", "1970:01:01T23:59:59", "soccer football match", "Just a great match! Barcelona 2 Real Madrid 3 Real Madrid wins the match!"
```

Comment: Its a csv file. You can use a csv reader which will handle it for you. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a csv with python, when one column has multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982437/how-to-parse-a-csv-with-python-when-one-column-has-multiple-lines)

Comment: Ok, thank you @fralau
So, I'll just use this ```column_wrapper``` that has been defined in that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **valid csv file** with multiline fields (except for the spaces between the `,` and `"`).

So you really should use a [csv parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of using `split()` and trying to parse the file yourself (this will also take care of the quotes etc.).

Comment: Ok, but csv reader escapes backslash in the newlines, so, I'll try to use the answer to the question @fralau shows me in the comment.

Comment: @Carmine Ok, but not sure what you mean with 'escaping backslash in the newlines'?

Comment: I'm saying that I didn't know how to handle the `\n` in the text passed to the csv reader.

Comment: @Carmine If you mean you want keep the lines separate, I would recommend to read it as a single field anyway and then split that field if needed (but that's probably what the answer you mention is about).

Comment: @Carmine module `csv` should parse `\n` correctly if you have real `\n` in file and not `\\n`. You can also see `\n` if you print list with strings - ie. `data = ["Hello \n World"]` and `print(data)` - but if you print every element manually then you see normal string - `print(data[0])`. It is not problem with data but with method which you may use to display it.