# Multiline CSV read using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, csv

Everyday we get CSV file from vendor and we need to parse them and insert it to database. We use single Python3 program for all the tasks.

The problem happening is with multiline CSV files, where the contents in the second lines are skipped.

```
48.11363;11.53402;81369;München;"";1.0;1962;I would need
help from 
Stackoverflow;"";"";"";289500.0;true;""
```

Here the field "I would need help from Stackoverflow" is spread in 3 lines.

The problem that happens is python3 only considers "I would Need" as a record and skips the rest of the part.

At present I am using below options to read from database :

```
with open(file_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,  delimiter=',' , quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
         {MY LOGIC}
```

Is there any way to include multiline CSV as a single record.

I understand, In pyspark, there is an option of option("multiline",True) but we don't want to use pyspark in first place.

Looking for options.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you know how many columns should be in one row?

Comment: can you show us the expected result please ? with rows and columns.

Comment: would this post help you ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982437/how-to-parse-a-csv-with-python-when-one-column-has-multiple-lines

Comment: Speak with the providers of the source data and have them sort it out, then send you a clean file.  You (your company) should not be responsible for cleaning their poor data quality.

Comment: @Alderven : Yes there would be 60 columns in 1 row.

Comment: Do you know the format of last column in a row? Will it be always `""`?

Comment: @Alderven : No it is not always like that. Any of the 60 columns randomly have "".