# how to read a csv file that has multiple lines within the same cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I apologize in advance for the image - I don't know how else to represent multiple lines in a single cell in stackoverflow.

I have a csv file that has multiple lines in a single cell like what is shown in table 1. I need each line, in each cell, to have its own column. Luckily each column has the same number of lines per cell. I.e. column-1 has 4 lines per row, column-2 has 2 lines per row, etc...

[image: Table 1]

I would like the results to look like table 2 where each line has a column. I have been trying to do this with splitlines() without success.

Table 2

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | c9 | c10 | c11 | c12 | c13 | c14 | c15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City of Pflugerville | New Residential Permits | 1-1-2010 12:00:00 AM thru 3-6-2021 12:00:00 AM | City | 13-23598 | 6-11-2013 120000 AM | Residential | Residential Building | 1901 Meandering Meadows Dr | Falcon Point Sec 4 South | Ryland Homes | 1101 Arrow Point Dr. Ste. # 101 Cedar Park TX 78613 | 208200 | Living - 2914 - Total - 3786.00 | Permits Issued in the City: 4573 |
| City of Pflugerville | New Residential Permits | 1-1-2010 12:00:00 AM thru 3-6-2021 12:00:00 AM | City | 13-23599 | 6-11-2013 000 | Residential | Residential Building | 3309 Pasqueflower Pass | Falcon Pointe Sec 12 | Ryland Homes | 1101 Arrow Point Dr Cedar Park TX 78613 | 267100 | Living - 3853 - Total - 4856.00 | Permits Issued in the City: 4573 |

If you can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you rather post the raw csv file top n rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work. Also pandas can handle multiline text pretty well so try using also pd.read_csv().

```
import csv

file_path = 'yourfile.csv'

with open(file_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: That's great! :)